# Add custom data-attribute inside script tag of custom JS

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, requirejs

I would like to add a custom data-attribute to a javascript injected in the frontend area using a custom module. 
My custom javascript is inserted using

```
    var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
                my_module: 'My_Module/js/my-script'
            }
        }
    };
```

My goal is to have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-foo = "bar" data-requiremodule="My_module/js/my_js" src="http://example.com/pub/static/version1559902439/frontend/Magento/luma/en_EN/My_module/js/my_js.js"></script>
```

where **data-foo** is my custom data-attribute.
I made some research in RequireJS documentation without success. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use onNodeCreated (needs requirejs 2.1.19 or newer) :

```
var config = {
paths: {
    slick:  'js/slick',
},
attributes: {
    "slick": {
      crossorigin: "anonymous" // your attributes here
    }
},
deps: [
    "js/main" 
],
shim: {
    'slick': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
},
onNodeCreated: function(node, config, name, url){
if(config.attributes && config.attributes[name]){
    Object.keys(config.attributes[name]).forEach(attribute => {
        node.setAttribute(attribute, config.attributes[name][attribute]);
        });
    }
}};
```

Take from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197939/add-crossorigin-attribute-to-script-tag-with-require-js

Comment: Thank for your suggestion I achieved my goal but I have two problems 1) requirejs version. 2) config the attribute data from backend setting

Comment: Hey @MatteoD how did you accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing the latest rev of Magento (2.4-develop) has [requirejs 2.1.11](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/web/requirejs/require.js), and upgrading will probably break things.

An alternative solution I have used is to manually place a script tag on the page, something like this:

```javascript
require([], function() {
    // Listen for the one trust library to load
    document.addEventListener('OneTrustLoaded', function() {
        // Dispatch custom event that the one trust library supports
        // once it has loaded
        var eOT = new Event('OneTrustGroupsUpdated');
        document.dispatchEvent(eOT);   
    }, false);

    // Load the one trust library by manually placing a script tag on the page
    // We do this because M2 has requirejs 2.1.11 and we'd need >= 2.1.19 in
    // order to achieve this directly via requirejs-config.js
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src     = 'https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js';
    script.type    = 'text/javascript';
    script.charset = 'UTF-8';
    script.dataset.documentLanguage('true');
    script.dataset.domainScript('customer-specific-value...');

    document.body.appendChild(script);
});
```